# Differing Performance on Horizontally Flipped Data

Tags: pytorch, autoencoder

I'm currently training a convolutional autoencoder on a dataset consisting of images of a circular object. This object should possess mirror symmetries and rotational symmetries. In order to debug my issues with augmentations, I tried training on data that had been entirely horizontally flipped. Despite the object being a circular object, the loss takes a distinctly different trajectory during training (this is repeatable) and results in different performance. Any ideas what might be causing this or how I might go about diagnosing this? I feel understanding this is a prerequisite to using augmentations. Thank you!

I'm using Pytorch and I've flipped the images using both Pytorch Transforms and PIL (both produce similar loss curves).